# How can I display my favicon icon , its there path is OK

Tags: html

I am not too much experience Developer Started Developing this site !Have tried all the ways but Not able to print the favicon Please Help 
Here's the site Url: http://onlinemcq.com/

Comment: I see a favicon there. Try to `Ctrl + Shift + R` on Win and `Cmd + Shift + R` on Mac to refresh browser's cache. Might be the problem in your case. As for now the question is not explained enough as there's no code or specific bug reproduction process.

Comment: There is a favicon

Comment: Yes yes It was Cache Issue Thanks alot :)